# Open source solution to convert office documents to PDF without using Office automation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, pdf-generation

Is there any open-source sdk that I can use in an ASP.Net application to convert any office document to pdf. (I specifically need to convert a DOCX to PDF, but would like the ability to convert Excel and powerpoint files too).

I know that I could use Office automation using code shown below, but I don't want to use Office automation, as its not recommended for use in non-interactive applications[KB257757](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

I have found that [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component/key-features.aspx) has a component that can be used for this (paid solution), but I was wondering if there were any open-source solutions out there.

```
//reference: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll
//using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
public static void Convert(string documentFilePath, string outputPath)
    {
        var ap = new Word.Application {Visible = false};

        var document = ap.Documents.Open(documentFilePath);

        document.ExportAsFixedFormat(outputPath,
                       WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,
                       OptimizeFor: WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint,
                       BitmapMissingFonts: true, DocStructureTags: false);

        document.Close();
    }
```

NOTE: I have seen some people recommend using OpenXML for this. But OpenXML does not provide you any method to convert an Office document to a PDF document.

Comment: Aspose also offer SaaSpose which is free or very cheap depending on your requirements.

Comment: DAI - I am looking for an open source solution. But thanks for that link, didnt know Aspose had a SAAS offering

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Did you have a look at LibreOffice? Obviously, with any third-party tool conversion quality will not be as high as with Microsoft Office, but the input converter for docx format in LibreOffice already is pretty ok.

Answer (score 4):

you can use libreOffice is free license under apache 2.0  i make an example for convert docx to ppt  and it's work perfectly ,  and you can convert to many types like pdf

here my exmaple:

```
    static string getLibreOfficePath()
    {
        switch (Environment.OSVersion.Platform)
        {
            case PlatformID.Unix:
                return "/usr/bin/soffice";
            case PlatformID.Win32NT:
                string binaryDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                //return binaryDirectory + "\\Windows\\program\\soffice.exe";
                return @"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe";
            default:
                throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Your OS is not supported");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string libreOfficePath = getLibreOfficePath();
        //to convert docx to pdf just change input file to docx
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(libreOfficePath, 
        string.Format("--convert-to pdf  C:\\test.ppt"));
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

        Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = procStartInfo, };
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        // Check for failed exit code.
        if (process.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            throw new LibreOfficeFailedException(process.ExitCode);
        }
    }
```

thanks , i hope it helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter).  This is free and open source and can do Doc->PDF well, DocX reasonably depending on your documents.  You might want to look at ODFCoverter to get a great DocX->ODT path and then JODConverter can do the ODT->PDF part.

Answer (score -1):

While it a single library, you could combine [NPoi](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) and [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) libraries together to accomplish your task. Both are .Net ports of their popular and robust Java counterparts.

Comment: While iTextSharp is an open source solution, it's licensed under AGPL.   Most probably it will be required to purchase a commercial license for iTextSharp in Raj's case.